# how to delete the string from the file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a file (`Test1.txt`) which contains email addresses:

```
abc@gmail.com
joe@yahoo.com
```

The same and a few extra email addresses may be present in another file (`Test2.txt`), e.g.:

```
abc@gmail.com
gpg@gmail.com
joe@yahoo.com
```

I want to delete the records from `Test2.txt` (`abc@gmail.com`, `joe@yahoo.com`) which are present in `Test1.txt`. The records which are common between `Test1.txt` and `Test2.txt` should get deleted from `Test2.txt`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[]^$.*&[]/\\&/g;s|.*|/^&$/d|' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

This generates a sed script from `file1` to process against `file2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{if(!($0 in a)){print}' test1 test2
```

or simply:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' test1 test2
```

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[$0];next}{if(!($0 in a)){print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                          ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Which flavour of unix you are using.It works for me.If you are on solaris use nawk instead of awk.

Comment: the second one is not deleting the matching email id from Test2.txt file.

Comment: This just outputs on the console. But does not delete from the file.If you want to delete then you need to wrap this up in a script and remove test2 and then redirect the output of the command to test2 again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so simple, command line is not SQL. A simple (although a little bit dirty) workaround:

```
cat Test1.txt Text2.txt Text2.txt|sort|uniq -c|awk '{if ($1==2) print $2;}'
```

This is correct only under the assumption that the emails are present at most once in each file, an assumption not necessarily true.

Comment: This is correct only under the assumption that the emails are present at most once in each file, an assumption not necessarily true..

Comment: one of the file can be empty

Answer (score 0):

isn't it a task for grep?

```
grep -Fwvf test1.txt test2.txt
```

Comment: I want to delete the matching records between these two files from Test2.txt

Comment: @Pooja25 and did you try my line? does it do the job you wanted?

Comment: I have tried in that way as well...but still its not returning ant output :(

Answer (score 0):

to get the common lines:

```
sort test1.txt test2.txt | uniq -d > common.txt
```

to get the lines from test2.txt that are not double (not content of common.txt)

```
sort common.txt test2.txt | uniq -u  > newtest2.txt
```

Comment: I want to delete the email id which are common between and not only sort them. can you please suggest the approach ?

Comment: after sorting common.txt in conjunction with test2.txt (without option -u) each id that is contained in test1 AND in test2 leads to a double line. uniq -u suppresses the double lines

Answer (score 0):

If the files are sorted then you can use the join command:

```
join -v 1 Test2.txt Test1.txt
```

`join` pairs input lines, `-v 1` removes lines matched with second file.

Were they not sorted, you can preprocess using sort:

```
sort Test1.txt > Text1.txt.sorted # and similarly for the second file
```

and run the join on the sorted files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one.

```
grep -xvf test1 test2 > test | cp test test2
```

its working as per your requirement but I doubt it's efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one:

```
grep -xvf test1 test2 > test|mv test test2
```

its working as per your requirement but doubt it's efficient!